# Is there a way to generate confluence wiki pages from javadocs?

Tags: wiki, javadoc, confluence

I'd like to put documentation on a confluence wiki for a project I'm working on, and I want to automatically generate some of the documentation from javadocs. Is there a plugin for confluence that makes this easy (did not see in preliminary search), alternatively has anyone written scripts to post wiki pages to confluence based on javadocs? An ant task might be cool, then I could have the wiki as a target.

Answer (score 2):

Confluence JavaDocs Macros is a plugin that will generate wiki pages from javadocs.  The downside is that a zip archive must be made of the javadocs and placed on the first page of a space, and multiple javadocs cannot co-exist in the same space.

The plugin is also not compatible with every version of Confluence.

And you might want to add javadocs to confluence if you only had a confluence server (or the confluence server is the primary place for documentation) to host your documentation...  It has happened before.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you upload javadoc into an editing system? This sounds rater odd. We created a apache server on which the project documentation is uploaded (which is created form Java as javadoc, and from some project documentation (which we also store in the project (inside SCM)).

Next to that we have a Wiki system, in which everyone can write all kind of stuff. It is easy in most wiki to make a external reference (to the Apache web-server, project documentation / javadoc pages).

The good thing about this is, that the project documentation can be re-generated through ant / maven / etc. and automaticly uploaded to some web-server. There is can only be red and not modified. That can only be done through the project sources. Which is good, because otherwise people start to edit the wiki pages, which then get replaced now and then, because a new build / release is created.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Docs Plugin: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/net.meixxi.confluence.docs.docs-plugin. This plugin enables you to upload and publish your JavaDocs and other HTML and JavaScript based content in Confluence.

Docs provides also a REST Interface in order to automate the publishing process. So, publishing the JavaDocs can become part of the Continuous Integartion Process. A technical documentation as well as a sample code can you find here: https://ricebean.net/confluence-docs

Comment: I found a cloud version of it: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1226266/docs-cloud-javadocs-phpdocs-doxygen-html-pages?tab=overview&hosting=cloud